# Import of Site from Dev To Production has made Site Actions > Site Settings throw 404s

Tags: 2010, variations

Our first import from our development site created all the variations and sites on the production site, but it didn't contain the full set of data. Now we have imported the full data set, but it had duplicated variations.

We cleaned out all the duplicates and are starting from scratch in creating our variations, but now all of the links related to _layouts in Site Settings throw a 404.

Answer (score 1):

What Dev vs Production means? Same AD, 2 different farms? Make sure you use same accounts in that case! Can you find the pages in the 14-hive, C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS folder??

Using variations also means that Variations-related controls have been configured -did u also copied all those??

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius